# Why does arcpy.TableToDomain_management require exclusive schema lock?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm talking about [arcpy.TableToDomain_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000025000000), ArcGIS Server 10.2

It seems that this function requires exclusive SDE database schema lock. Something that we can't accept.

We have ESRI domains but we want to extend them with additional attributes. (I think we are not alone doing this). So when user updates our "extended domains" we store values to our tables and then update domains by invoking our tbx with python code that simply calls TableToDomain_management.

That **fails** because exclusive SDE database schema lock can't be acquired because other users have the database open (in arcmap, mostly on web).

It's strange because first natural guess was to test if we can edit domains in arccatalog while other users have the sde database open. No problem: we could.

So why does arcpy.TableToDomain_management lock SDE DB?
Do you know any NIMs, hotfixes, ets. that can help us?

More details.

The guy with ArcGIS 10.1 tells that it happens only if he runs it on server, e.g. published sd (service definition file). If he runs it on 32 bit desktop (arcmap, arcatalog), tbx file is used of course, he doesn't get schema lock.

== Edit 1

How do we update domains (or given the issues: How do we want to update domains)? Plain code-value domains; no magic here. User story below.

Web user that has (enough) administrative rights edits domain values (not codes). (S)He also deletes unnecessary code-value pairs. And also adds new code-value pairs.

Therefore we use TableToDomain_management, not AddCodedValueToDomain_management.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't *need* exclusive schema lock but acquires it anyway; I think internally the tool removes the domain and then re-creates it which would need exclusive access. Can you execute Add Coded Value to Domain http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000001v000000 without locking?

Comment: That links to NIM103667 as mentioned in ORA-55378 answer.

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson It doesn't need exclusive schema lock, I know. We hand an implementation of the same in ArcObjects (actually .NET wrapper over it) and it worked; probably works so far, but it was in AGS 10.1. Now we're re-architecturing stuff to be closer to skies and clouds and got this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be hitting this. This is reproducible with the TableToDomain tool as well. Try the workaround that succeeds for the Add Coded Value tool, that might do it for your case as well.

[NIM103667](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMTAzNjY3)

Submitted    Jul 23, 2014 8:05 AM

Synopsis

While executing the Add Coded Value to Domain tool, the following error message is displayed: "Cannot get exclusive schema lock."

Workaround

Grant full editing privileges (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) to the domain owner on all the feature classes utilizing the domain being updated.